# Set dropdownlist selected value inside selectedindexchanged event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist that I am binding at run time and it has first item as "--Select--".

I have a specific requirement where if a user selects a different item from dropdown list then inside the `selectedindexchanged` event I am checking that if selected item is not first then apply logic and at the end of the code reset it back to first item.

```
protected void ddlExistingGoals_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if (ddlExistingGoals.SelectedValue != "0")
    {
        ---- Perform Logic ----
        ddlExistingGoals.Items.FindByValue("0").Selected = true;
    }
    else
    {
        clearAllControls();
    }
}
```

When I write above code then it does not render grid data inside page and also tried dropdown preRender method as below:

```
protected void ddlExistingGoals_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlExistingGoals.SelectedValue != "0")
    {
        ddlExistingGoals.Items.FindByValue("0").Selected = true;
    }
}
```

In both the cases it neither changing dropdown selected index nor it rendering other control logic data on page. It is exceptional and I want to know whether is it possible to change selected index inside dropdown's selectedindexchanged event ?! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If the `selection changed` doesn't fire, it means you did not hooked up a handler to the event properly. Use debugger to check whether it works or not. Also, `SelectedValue` does not check for your index, but for the string value of selected element. If you're expecting `--Select--"`, you should check against `"--Select--"`, not `"0"`. For index checking or setting you've got `SelectedIndex` property.

Comment: Can you add your Dropdown Binding Code? and have you set "AutoPostBack" Property of Dropdown ?

Comment: As @MayurBorad stated, you need to set `AutoPostBack` to true.

Comment: selectedindexchanged event already executing and i have set autopostback true so these are not the case. My question is why i can not change its selected index using find by text/value inside "selectedindexchanged" event ?

Comment: Can you add your Dropdown binding code? Is it call on every postback event?

Comment: -----
ddlExistingGoals.DataSource = dtGoalMaster;
                ddlExistingGoals.DataTextField = dtGoalMaster.Columns["Main Goal Name"].ToString();
                ddlExistingGoals.DataValueField = dtGoalMaster.Columns["Goal_Main_Id"].ToString();
                ddlExistingGoals.DataBind();
                ddlExistingGoals.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("---Select---", "0"));

and it is not being call on every postback only first time.

Comment: Where you adding "--Select--" ?

Comment: have you set appenddatabounditems= "true" on dropdown?

Comment: Not really but do you think appenddatabounditems has anything to do with setting first index of dropdown inside selectedindexchanged event ? and even i just tried with appenddatabounditems="true" have no luck!

Comment: Yes, appenddatabounditems  property is used for adding Item with Datasource.  Have you able to see '--Select--' On dropdown

Comment: yes of course i can see "--Select--" on dropdown without appenddatabounditems because let's see my above comment i inserting first item after databind call.

Comment: Set ddlExistingGoals.SelectedValue = "0"; instad of ddlExistingGoals.Items.FindByValue("0").Selected = true;

Comment: this way its working but i want to know what is the reason i can not set value using find by text/value inside selectedindexchanged ? any specific reason ?

Comment: You can check for selected item using jquery.. that will make easy for u

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that .SelectedValue and .Selected is the same. .Selected is a
property of just one item. It has no way of knowing what's going on with the
other items. Whereas .SelectedIndex is a property of Dropdown, and the Dropdown can
first unselect previously selected item.

The ListItem has no idea what list (or lists) it belongs to, so how can it
select itself in other lists?

because "Selected" is a property of ListItem, not of ddl. By setting
..Selected, you don't select the item in the owner list, as in the case.of
setting .SelectedItem. Rather you set the item on it's own, and the owners
have to fight whether the item should be selected or no.

use

```
ListItem myitem = ddlChoseModel.Items.FindByValue(ModelID);
ddlChoseModel.SelectedValue = myitem.Value;
```